# Reading Mifare card via web app using Android device's NFC

Tags: android, nfc, progressive-web-apps

I want to find out if this is possible, to have a web app read off information from a Mifare card, by tapping the card against a NFC-enabled Android device.

I have been searching this for quite some time, and it seems like as of now it's only limited to experimental implementation - https://whatwebcando.today/nfc.html

Or am I truly better off with a native Android app?

Edit:
Thanks to all who replied. We have been trying out the Web NFC API as specified here https://w3c.github.io/web-nfc/, turned on the experimental features of Chrome on the Android device, but it always return a null value when we tap the Mifare card on the device. Are we missing out any steps, or is it really a technical limitation of the API at this moment, since it's still not considered as a stable specification?

Comment: I think you're right that it's not yet feasible with web app. Check it in this [thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/dIbUdDU9a6E). You may also refer with this [MIFARE Classic Tool (MCT)](https://github.com/ikarus23/MifareClassicTool) which is an Android NFC-App for reading, writing, analyzing, etc. MIFARE Classic RFID-Tags.

Answer (score 0):

I think on mid-term even WebNFC will be restricted to (reading & writing) NDEF messages, similar to what Apple is currently doing on iOS.
So if you want to read info like UID or raw data out of a MIFARE card, you need to write a native app. Be aware that MIFARE (Classic) is not supported by all phones, even when they have NFC. 
If you want to use a framework like ionic or Cordova, you can also use the NDEF plugin (https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc)